# Why does this not work? Flash As3, if added child is at frame something?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement, addchild

This is my code help me please its really frustrating!
I have a movieclip in my library and added it with AS3 to the stage.
That part was easy. But now i want to control that movieclip.
If introScene "introClass" Reaches frame 120 then i want to remove that movieclip
and replace it with another one. The problem is the if statement doesn't work.
I also tried getChildByName but that didn't work either.

```
var introClass = new introScene;
addChild(introClass);
introClass.x = 640;
introClass.y = 387;
```

> /****************INTRO-SCENE****************/

```
introClass.addEventListener(Event, introLoaded);

function introLoaded(event):void{

    if(introClass == 120 ){
        trace("Frame Reached")
    }
}
```

i tried this and this also doesn't work :(

```
introClass.addEventListener(Event, introLoaded);

function introLoaded (e:Event):void{

    if(MovieClip(introClass).currentFrame == 120){
        trace("120 complete")
    }
}
```

Comment: You need more detail.  What is the error you're receiving?   One thing I spot right away is you're missing `()` after instantiating `introScene`.  Should be `introClass = new introScene();`

Comment: Also, your passing a display object to your `introLoaded` function, which is expecting an `Event` object presumably

Comment: There is no error it does nothing. I added introScene to the stage from library. And my goal was if the movieclip symbol introScene reached frame 120. Than another listener will be activated.

Comment: if i do introClass.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, introLoaded); instead of introClass.addEventListener(Event, introLoaded); than it works but thats not the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong statement:

```
introClass.addEventListener(Event, introLoaded);
```

You need to pass a string to addEventListener. Event type name is converted to a string at runtime which adds a event listener to "flash.events.Event" or something. And your object obviously doesn't have this event. You need to use Event.ENTER_FRAME for example.

Comment: is there another way? or something different than ENTER_FRAME because its only good for things that got loaders and stuff so you can see progress.

Comment: With ENTER_FRAME the code does exactly what you want. Otherwise you can dispatch a custom event at frame 120 `dispatchEvent(new Event("bla"));` and listen for that `introClass.addEventListener("bla", introLoaded);`.